# Agda: Which part does this type introduce universe inconsistency?

Tags: type-theory, proof-assistants

I was trying to prove following lemma,

```
  my_thm : ¬ (∀ {M : Set} (P Q : M → M → Set) →
    (∀ x → ∃ M , λ y → P x y ∨ Q x y) →
    (∀ x → ∃ M , P x) ∨ (∀ x → ∃ M , Q x))
  my_thm = ?
```

while Agda gives following mistake:

```
Set₁ != Set
when checking that the expression
{M : Set} (P Q : M → M → Set) →
(∀ x → ∃ M , λ y → P x y ∨ Q x y) →
(∀ x → ∃ M , P x) ∨ (∀ x → ∃ M , Q x)
has type Set
```

honestly, in my untrained eyes, this type looks entirely routine to me, and it shouldn't introduce universe inconsistency.

all extra quantifier and connectivities are defined as following,

```
  data _∨_ : Set → Set → Set where
    inl : {A B : Set} → A → A ∨ B
    inr : {A B : Set} → B → A ∨ B
  infixl 20 _∨_

  ¬_ : Set → Set
  ¬ P = P → False
  infix 40 ¬_

  data ∃_,_ : (A : Set) → (A → Set) → Set where
    ex : {A : Set}{P : A → Set} → (x : A) → (ev : P x) → ∃ A , P
  infix 10 ∃_,_
```

which part introduces `Set1` in this code?

---

ok, it turns out it's caused by negation: `¬_ : Set → Set`. However, I still not understand. why this innocent looking function does not do what I want? what's the correct way of implementing it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The term you're applying `¬_` to is large: it quantifies over all `M : Set` and therefore has type `Set 1`. So instead of `¬_ : Set -> Set` you need `¬_ : Set 1 -> Set 1`.

A more general solution it to make `¬_` level polymorphic as in [the standard library](https://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Relation.Nullary.html#414): you will be able to use this definition of negation across the board no matter how large the thing you're negating is.

Comment: yeah, after I took a shower I realized that too. i think `->` is also a type constructor, the universe of which is the larger one of the ones of both operands. is that understanding correct?

Comment: You're correct.